# Handle statusCode: 403 for Image.network

Tags: image, flutter, dart, exception

Can you help resolve how to catch the exception when the image does not exist or image return code `HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403`

```
    dynamic _getImage() {
    try {
      return Image.network(
          "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1343501/screenshots/4789104/box_800_-601_2.gif",
          height: 96.0,
          width: 96.0,
          fit: BoxFit.cover);
    } catch (e) {
      return Icon(Icons.print);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, looks like there is no solution yet from Flutter network images side, and the try-catch closure is not helping there, hence I came up with a work around for it that handled it for me, although I don't like it but couldn't find a better solution:

```
  bool imageReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkImageValidity(widget.url);
  }

  checkImageValidity(String url) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(image!);
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          imageReady = true; // It's valid
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // TODO nothing special to do here
    }
  }

  dynamic _getImage() {
    try {
      return imageReady
          ? Image.network(
              "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1343501/screenshots/4789104/box_800_-601_2.gif",
              height: 96.0,
              width: 96.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover)
          : Icon(Icons.print);
    } catch (e) {
      return Icon(Icons.print);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a PullRequest https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18424 that is supposed to allow handling errors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how is that will help solve the Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,

Comment: I didn't have a chance yet to have a closer look.

Comment: Actually this merge request didn't help in handling this issue.